# Crear array en php con datos personalizados

Tags: php

Hola estoy tratando de crear un array para ahorrarme consultas recursivas a mysql.

La idea es asociar el id de un registro en mysql a su nombre y asi en vez de estar haciendo consultas a mysql lo que puedo hacer es recorrer el array para mostrar el dato.

En principio la forma que he pensado de hacerlo seria con esta sintaxis `idcosa => nombre`

El caso es que para hacerlo tengo que recorrer un bucle con la consulta en cuestión. Pero todo lo que encuentro para construir arrays me auto genera el valor del array ( el primer valor ) y claro ese dato es el que necesito para localizar el nombre. el código que estoy usando ( que no va porque no tengo ni papa de como hacerlo pero bueno, yo lo pongo por si sirve de algo ).

```
$tallas = [];
foreach($CAtallas as $DAtallas) { $tallas = $DAtallas["id"].'=>'.$DAtallas["Conf1"]; }
  print_r($tallas);
```

De todas formas si alguien cree que para evitar estar consultando a mysql los codigos internos para que el usuario lo entienda hay otra forma mejor que un array estoy abierto a cambiar el funcionamiento.

estoy probando con esto usando la respuesta de flowen, pero no me da resultados

```
$tallas = array();
foreach($tallas as $DAtallas){ 
   $tallas[$DAtallas["id"]]  = $DAtallas["Conf1"];
}

  print_r($tallas);
```

usando el codigo de gdp me da estos resultados:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 241 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 24 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [1] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 240 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 25 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [2] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 239 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 26 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [3] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 238 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 27 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [4] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 237 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 28 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [5] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 236 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 29 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [6] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 235 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 30 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [7] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 234 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 31 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [8] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 233 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 32 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [9] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 232 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 33 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [10] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 129 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 34 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [11] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 36 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 35 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [12] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 38 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 36 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [13] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 39 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 37 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [14] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 59 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 38 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [15] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 60 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 39 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [16] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 61 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 40 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [17] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 62 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 41 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [18] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 63 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 42 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [19] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 64 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 43 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [20] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 65 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 44 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [21] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 66 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 45 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [22] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 67 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 46 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [23] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 128 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 47 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [24] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 244 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 48 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) [25] => Array ( [Conf_id] => 243 [Conf_que] => Talla [Conf1] => 49 [Conf2] => [Conf3] => [Conf4] => [Conf5] => [Conf6] => [Conf7] => [Conf8] => [Conf9] => [Conf10] => [Conf11] => [Conf12] => [Conf13] => [Conf14] => [Conf15] => [Conf16] => [Conf17] => [Conf18] => [Conf19] => [Conf20] => [Conf21] => ) )
```

pero no es el formato que intento conseguir... intento que ponga solo [Conf_id] => [Conf1] que son el id y el nombre de la talla.

Comment: A ver, pero es un array anidado eso con muchas claves denominadas id? si no no te va a funcionar... haz un printr de CAtallas y pega aqui el contenido de tu array.

Comment: Lo ultimo que has puesto es imposible que funcione! Si tallas esta vacio como lo vas a recorrer y guardarlo sobre si mismo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente recorre el array que contiene los registros y vas asignado el "id" al `key` y el "Conf1" (Suponiendo que sea el nombre) al `value`.

```
$tallas = array();
foreach($CAtallas as $DAtallas){ 
   $tallas[$DAtallas["id"]]  = $DAtallas["Conf1"] ;
}
```

Comment: pero CAtallas no es otro array? me he perdido un poco en la pregunta creo yo jajaja

Comment: solo me saca un resultado :_(

Comment: Has puesto el foreach?

Comment: asi lo había puesto.. actualizo la pregunta con la forma que lo tengo ahora según entiendo tu codigo

Comment: Actualizo @Killpe

Comment: sigue dándome un resultado :(

Comment: @Marcos poniendo CAtallas en vez de tallas tampoco me saca ningún resultado

Comment: @Killpe, te dejo [esta demo](http://rextester.com/KVXD91601) para que veas si debería funcionar.

Comment: @Marcos en efecto ahi si funciona y saca justo lo que necesito... ahora me falta que mi codigo devuelva resultados XD... a ver si lo consigo

Comment: Conseguido :) es que no era id si no Conf_id por eso no me daba resultados

Answer (score 2):

Creo que ya te lo han respondido "Flowen", aunque no ha puesto bien el nombre de la variable del índice del array. El siguiente código debería funcionar.

```
$tallas = [];
foreach($CAtallas as $DAtallas) {
   $tallas[$DAtallas["Conf_id"]] = $DAtallas["Conf1"];
}
```